# MP3 song not played in Firefox using jPlayer?

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

The MP3 songs are not being played in Firefox. I tried the below code. How can I solve this problem?

```
{
    title:"<?php echo $value['varsongName'];?>",
    mp3:"<?php echo $download; ?>",
    oga:"<?php echo $download; ?>"
}, <?php } ?>
], {
    swfPath: "js",
    solution: 'html, flash',
    supplied: "oga, mp3",
    wmode: "opaque",
    solution:"html,flash",
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

The Song play in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the same filename for MP3 and OGG. Since they are two different formats, they can't be the same file. Firefox natively supports OGG, and will attempt to play it (because you list that source first). When it gets an MP3 file instead, it doesn't know what to do.

Unless you actually have an OGG encoding of your file, you should just remove all references to that format and just provide the MP3 only.

Edit: I notice also that you define the "solution" property twice. This is technically an error and Firefox may be being pedantic over it.

Comment: I deleted all reference oga format.But Still is not play?

Comment: Have you tried removing the duplicate `solution` property on your object?